# R ggplot heatmap with multiple rows having separate legends on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, legend, heatmap

I'm trying to make one heatmap using ggplot2 that contains 3 types of variables where each need their own independent legend/scale.

I am able to plot them all in one heatmap (pictured below), but I am having trouble separating them to have their own legend. My three categories are the row "Score", "samp1" and the rest of the data. I would like each of these to have their own independent legends with their respective ranges.

My only addition would be to have the row score have a green,yellow,red (low, mid,high) color scheme, if that is possible to include in this question.

[image: an image of what I have so far]

This is the code I am using to create that graph

```
library(ggplot2)
test_data <- read.csv("test_table.csv", row.names = 1)

ggplot(test_data, aes(x=sample, y=id, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), # lables vertical
        strip.text.y = element_blank()) +  #remove facet bar on y 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "lightblue") +
  ggtitle("test table") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(test_data$category), 
             cols = vars(test_data$group), scales = "free", space="free_y") #facets to add gaps
```

I have used facets to separate the data by sample and by the 3 categories I described above. I was hoping to use this grouping to create their own legends as well, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zH8vpLQVcCMW-7OJyFO9e2PBueqhqMv/view?usp=sharing) to download the data (pre-melted).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The other approach I was considering is having them as 3 separate graphs and then trying to combine them. If that is the way to go, I could provide separated data as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `ggnewscale` package like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = filter(test_data, category == "1 score"), aes(x = sample, y = id, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red", midpoint = 4, name = "Score") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_raster(data = filter(test_data, category == "2 samp1"), aes(x = sample, y = id, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "lightblue", name = "Sample1") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_raster(data = filter(test_data, category == "3 samp2"), aes(x = sample, y = id, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "lightblue", name = "Sample2") +
  ggtitle("test table") +
  facet_grid(
    rows = vars(category),
    cols = vars(group), scales = "free", space = "free_y"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    strip.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest next approach. Split data by groups and then build a separate plot for each group with a function. Finally use `purrr` and `patchwork` to join all plots with the diferent legends. Here the code:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Load data
test_data <- read.csv("test_table.csv", row.names = 1)
#Split into list
List <- split(test_data,test_data$group)
#Function for plots
myfun <- function(x)
{
  G <- ggplot(x, aes(x=sample, y=id, fill = value)) + 
    geom_raster() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), # lables vertical
          strip.text.y = element_blank()) +  #remove facet bar on y 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "lightblue") +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(x$category), 
               cols = vars(x$group), scales = "free", space="free_y")
  return(G)
}
#Apply
List2 <- lapply(List,myfun)
#Plot
reduce(List2, `+`)+plot_annotation(title = 'My plot')
```

The output:

[image]

You can explore further about `patchwork` and how to join multiple plots.

Comment: you can use `patchwork::wrap_plots()` instead of `Reduce`

Comment: This is awesome, I will have to keep patchwork in mind for future projects. I really appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to make 3 plots and stick them together, but given the facets are different shapes, this isn't ideal. You could use the `ggnewscale` package as per Stefan, which is easier now it is on CRAN, but if you want to do it in a single ggplot without add-ons it *is* possible. You just need to plot a `geom_point` that is made of large solid squares. This allows you to use a colour scale as well as a fill scale.

```r
ggplot(test_data, aes(x=sample, y=id, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = id, colour = value), size = 12, shape = 15) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
        strip.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "lightblue") +
  ggtitle("test table") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(test_data$category), 
             cols = vars(test_data$group),  scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(rep(0, 19), 1, 0, 0), guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "orange", "gold", "yellow"))
```

[image]